# SQL Join and reservation

Tags: sql, join, where-clause

I've been asked to join two separate tables and find the book number and titles for all books reserved in june 1993. The database for the reservations is

```
Book_reservation (kb_bor_no, kb_isbn, kb_reserve_date) VALUES  
('B0000006','09952500','20-NOV-1991');

Book_reservation (kb_bor_no, kb_isbn, kb_reserve_date) VALUES
('B0000004','45002286','13-JUN-1993');

Book_reservation (kb_bor_no, kb_isbn, kb_reserve_date) VALUES
('B0000004','86007906','13-JUN-1993');

Book_reservation (kb_bor_no, kb_isbn, kb_reserve_date) VALUES
('B0000009','55213462','30-JUN-1993');

Book_reservation (kb_bor_no, kb_isbn, kb_reserve_date) VALUES
('B0000007','45002286','01-JUL-1993');

Book_reservation (kb_bor_no, kb_isbn, kb_reserve_date) VALUES
('B0000002','72216393','02-JUL-1993');

Book_reservation (kb_bor_no, kb_isbn, kb_reserve_date) VALUES
('B0000008','45002286','03-JUL-1993');

Book_reservation (kb_bor_no, kb_isbn, kb_reserve_date) VALUES
('B0000007','45000918','11-JUL-1993');
```

And so far I have this code:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    Book_Book.kb_title, Book_Reservation.kb_isbn
FROM  
    Book_Book 
JOIN 
    Book_Reservation ON (Book_Book.kb_isbn = Book_Reservation.kb_isbn);
```

But I do not know how to filter it to only show the books reserved from june 1993, I do not know what to put in a `WHERE` clause below ON

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT Book_Book.kb_title, Book_reservation.kb_isbn
FROM Book_Book JOIN Book_reservation
ON (Book_Book.kb_isbn = Book_reservation.kb_isbn)
WHERE kb_reserve_date>='01-JUN-1993' AND
kb_reserve_date < '01-JUL-1993'
```